# Selecting documents between user-specified dates using linq with mongodb

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to MongoDB and I've run in to a problem with a query. The query tries to find all documents between 2 DateTime values. I have previously been able to run a similar query with the desired result, however with a different database schema. By applying the same query with my current database schema the query doesn't work. 
The query is as follows:

```
            var query =
            (
                from t in rdb.TimeStampsCollection.AsQueryable()
                where t.dt > lowDate && t.dt < highDate
                select t.rbt_List 
            );
```

The rdb.TimeStampsCollection is mapped to a C# class called TimeStamp. Except for the BSonObjectId, the class contains a DateTime and a list of objects from a class called RobotTimeStamps.

```
public class TimeStamp
{
    public BsonObjectId Id;
    public DateTime dt;
    public List<RobotTimeStamp> rbt_List;

    public TimeStamp(DateTime date)
    {
        this.dt = date;
        this.rbt_List = new List<RobotTimeStamp>();
    }
}


public class RobotTimeStamp
{
    public BsonObjectId Id;
    public int robotID;
    public int productionCellId;
    public DateTime timeStamp;
    public double p1;
    public double p2;
    public double p3;
    public double q1;
    public double q2;
    public double q3;
    public double s1;
    public double s2;
    public double s3;
    public double pf1;
    public double pf2;
    public double pf3;
// constructor
}
```

So the query I'm trying to run doesn't work. It never returns any documents from my collection. Currently the DateTime lowDate and highDate are set with a precision of seconds. Funny thing is, if I set the DateTime using the built-in DateTime.Now the query works.

```
// Not working
DateTime lowDate = new DateTime(2015,3,26,22,27,0);
DateTime highDate = new DateTime(2015,3,26,22,30,0);

//working
DateTime lowDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
DateTime highDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
```

As mentioned in the beginning of the post, I have previously been able to get the desired result by setting the DateTime values as shown above. However with my current database structure this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is probably a better way to solve this issue but this did the trick for me.

```
        DateTime ownLow = new DateTime(2015, 3, 28, 21, 28, 13, 0);
        DateTime ownHigh = new DateTime(2015, 3, 28, 21, 28, 20, 0);

        string stringLow = ownLow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ");
        string stringHigh = ownHigh.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ");

        DateTime lowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stringLow);
        DateTime highDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stringHigh);
```

In order for me to get this query to work I had to create the DateTime, parse it to a string and then convert it back to a DateTime value.